# How to create a floating widget hovering other widgets on Windows?

Tags: wxwidgets

Assume we have a `wxWebView` control in both window hierarchy and sizer hierarchy. How do we create a static text "loading" hovering above the `wxWebView` on Windows? Thanks.

It's straightforward on Linux. Create a `wxStaticText` of which the parent/owner is the same as the `wxWebView` and that's all. Unfortunately, it won't work on Windows. The `wxStaticText` is invisible because it is covered by the `wxWebView`. I've tried many ways, including calling their method `Lower` and `Raise` to adjust their z-orders, but in vain.

I also tried putting the text into a `wxFrame` and use `samples/shaped/` as an example, but on the second thought, the new top-level frame may cover the GUI of other processes. So it isn't a good design.

Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: this is a bad design anyway. Why not use wxBusyCursor or or write `Loading...` in the status bar of the web view frame?

Comment: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_busy_info.html

Comment: @lgor As far as I know, a panel cannot have status bar. Anyway, I put the static text into the sizer and use the sizer to hide the static text when it isn't needed. The result is acceptable to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets doesn't support overlapping child controls, so you would need to use a different top level window for your floating control, typically a `wxPopupWindow` -- then you could either draw your text in it or make `wxStaticText` its child.